# canvas text is not drawn on an image

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to draw an image from an url into a canvas:

```
function addImage(url) {

  canvas.clear();

  fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
    oImg.selectable = false;
    canvas.add(oImg);
  });

};
```

works.
Now I also want to draw a text on top of that image with this function:

```
function addText(text_to_add) {

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(text_to_add,10,50);

};
```

To make sure the text is drawn ON TOP of the image, I understand that I first need to draw the image and THEN the text, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addImage('/path/to/image/image.jpg'); addText('Hello World');">Click me to Draw image and text</a>
```

The result is, that the text is always drawn BEHIND the image. I see the text for a mili-second and then the image overlays the text. I want the text to be drawn on TOP of the image.

I have added this jsfiddle but somehow it does not run. Maybe a problem with the fabric.js library.
http://jsfiddle.net/02vrr15d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `addText` from `onclick`, and add to `addImage`

```
function addImage(url) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (oImg) {
        oImg.selectable = false;
        canvas.add(oImg);
        addText('Hello World');
    });
};
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/02vrr15d/1/)

Comment: Yes that works. Can someone explain why it has to be like that and that I cannot do it like in my example?

Comment: @DonMB You code does not work because `.fromURL` is asynchronous function, that's why text always BEHIND image. When you click on link you request image from url, and you don't wait while this image will be downloaded.